# java 8 spring spEL repeatable binding slows each iterations

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-el

I'm using spEL 4.0.0.RELEASE to bind http parameters to java objects.
I notice some strange problem while using expression parser multiple time: each invocation takes more time (constant). This happens only on java 8. On java 7 all ok.

Here is example code:

```
package ru.tersys.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test instance = new Test();

    Table t = new Table();
    Column c = new Column();
    t.getColumns().add(c);      

    int counter = 10;       
    while (counter-- > 0)
    {
        instance.doTest("t", t);
    }
}

ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();

public void doTest(String prefix, Object obj)
{
    Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
     int counter = 0;       
        String el = "t.columns[0].name";         

        context.setVariable(prefix, obj);
        String prefixWithDot = prefix + ".";

        int count = 400;

        while (count -- > 0)
        {
            if (el.startsWith(prefixWithDot))
            {
                parser.parseExpression("#"+el).setValue(context, "testColumnName");
                counter++;
            }
        }           
System.out.println("bind duration sec =  " + (Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() - d.getTime())/1000 + " param count = " + counter);        

}




static class Table
{
    public Table()
    {
        columns = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public ArrayList<Column> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }
    public void setColumns(ArrayList<Column> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
    private ArrayList<Column> columns;

}

static class Column
{
    public Column()
    {

    }
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

}
```

jdk 8 output:

```
bind duration sec =  1 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  3 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  5 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  7 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  9 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  12 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  14 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  16 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  19 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  22 param count = 400
```

java 7 output:

```
bind duration sec =  0 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  0 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  0 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  0 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  0 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  0 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  0 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  0 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  0 param count = 400
bind duration sec =  0 param count = 400
```

Is this bug or feature? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I suggest profiling with VisualVM to reveal where this time is spent.

Comment: Using `Calendar` for this purpose is the strangest thing I’ve ever seen. Do you know [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())?

Comment: Hello, Marko. Yes, I tested it with jVisualVm. Hot method is org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.asCollection(). It seems that there is some issue with collections.

Comment: You get that from the "hot spots" list? This doesn't necessarily tell the full story. Analyzing a snapshot's stacktraces and finding the bottleneck method call is much more reliable. Sorry if that's what you have already done.

Comment: No, I take it from "call tree". In hotspot tab the most call method is [java.lang.Class.getClassLoader() 97.0107 22 685 ms (97%) 22 685 ms]. This is leaf of org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.asCollection() method call in call tree.

Comment: Problem was solved by switching to spring-el version 4.0.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be related to this [JIRA Issue "Performance issues with SerializableTypeWrapper on Java 1.7.0_51"](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11335), which was fixed in 4.0.1.